# Destroying socket.io websockets

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io

I will be creating dozens of web sockets and need to destroy the ones that no longer have anyone connected to it.

I am guessing that setting all references to null will not be enough. I want to save as much memory as possible.

Thanks